# Impedir acceso a página usando rol en sesión

Tags: php, mysql

Llevo horas buscando información en SO y otros sitios sobre sesiones PHP por roles. La información es muy buena, extensa y bien documentada pero ese es mi problema, demasiado extensa y demasiado pesada.

**Quiero lograr el código más corto y escueto posible, pues no necesito más.**

Inicio sesión en un login.php que me valida los campos: usuario y contraseña, los cuales están almacenados en una BBDD de MySQL.

Si es correcto puedo ver el home.php y otras páginas (Hasta aquí todo perfecto).

Ahora resulta que tengo una página "privado.php" a la cual sólo pueden acceder ciertos usuarios.

Para eso tengo en mi tabla un tercer campo llamado "acceso" con los únicos valores "si" y "no":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo validar en el inicio de sesión ese tercer campo? Si el valor es "si" tengo permiso a "privado.php", de lo contrario no puedo ingresar.

Esto es lo que tengo:

---

**LOGIN.PHP**

```html
<body>
<form action="validation.php" method="POST">

<fieldset>

<p><label for="email">Usuario</label></p>
<p><input type="text" name="login" id="email" required></p>

<p><label for="password">Contraseña</label></p>
<p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></p>

<br><br>

<p><input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Ingresar"></p>         

</fieldset>

</form>

</body>
```

---

**VALIDATION.PHP**

```html
<body>

<?php
try {

$base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=PRUEBAS", "root", "");

$base->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :password";

$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

$login=htmlentities (addslashes($_POST["login"]));

$password=htmlentities (addslashes($_POST["password"]));

$resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);

$resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

$resultado->execute();

$numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();

if($numero_registro!=0) {

  session_start ();

  $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];

  if (isset($_POST['url']) && strlen($_POST['url'])) {
          // redirecciona a la url
          header("location:".$_POST['url']);
      }

      // redirecciona al index x defecto
      header("location:home.php");

  } else {

   echo "<script>
              alert('Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos, por favor intente nuevamente.');
              window.location= 'login.php'
      </script>";
}


} catch (\Exception $e) {

die ("Error: " . $e->getMessage());


}

     ?>

  </body>
```

---

Y así es como valido la sesión en la cabecera de la página "home.php" (y otras más).

```html
 <?php

     session_start();
     if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){

       header("Location:login.php");

     }

    ?>
```

---

**Resumiendo**

Pido disculpas, la pregunta es un poco extensa. Necesito impedir el acceso a una página "privado.php". Por ejemplo, ¿Debería validar el campo "acceso" de mi tabla en mi *validation.php* o en la cabecera de esa página que quiero restringir?

---

**EDITO**

Estuve consultando al respecto y puedo lograrlo si almaceno el inicio de sesión de forma booleana, dejando el campo acceso de forma INT con valores 1 y 2. Valor 2 para admins y valor 1 para todos los demás.

[Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42476700/9609518) en el sitio original de SO es muy similar pero no logro implementarla del todo en mi código.

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Intentaste guardar en session, en el archivo validation.php, el dato acceso de tu tabla? asociado al usuario que inicia sesión. Luego en base a esa información, guardada en session, podrás controlar quienes pueden acceder o no a privado.php

Comment: Hola, gracias. No se con exactitud cómo identificar ese campo en mi validador de sesión. Intenté con un SELECT acceso FROM * mitabla where '$usuario' AND password = '$password' y luego en las cabeceras restringidas usar SWITCH pero no tuve éxito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a utilizar el ID del usuario de la tabla y con PHP le pides a MySQL si ese usuario tiene sí o no, lo  igualas a "si" y si no es igual que se redireccione a index.php o a donde quieras
En cuanto llegue a casa edito la respuesta agregando código de ejemplo, de igual manera si tienes algo de experiencia en PHP deberías entender lo que estoy diciéndote, espero te sea de ayuda, luego vuelvo a darte el ejemplo :)

Edito:

```
<?php
mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "","tubasededatos");
$dato = mysqli_query("SELECT acceso FROM tubasededatos WHERE id=$_SESSION['usuario']");
$si = "si";
if (strcmp($dato, $si) == 0) {
}
else {
header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Creo que sería así, estoy del móvil ahora... Disculpa si hay algún error, pero creo que sería así.

Comment: Esto reemplaza mi validation.php? Debería llamar normal la sesión en mi privado.php?

Comment: Hola, no, no reemplaza tu validación.php, este código solo se debe poner en las páginas "privadas" al principio del codigo, como el sessions. Saludos, y espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Tengo el siguiente error al acceder al privado.php = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\ejemplo\privado.php on line 3

Comment: Esta es la línea 3: $dato = mysqli_query("SELECT acceso FROM mibasedatos WHERE id=$_SESSION['usuario']"); Intenté también llamando la tabla en vez de la BD en esa misma línea

Comment: Pon arriba de $dato la siguiente variable: $usuario=$_SESSION['usuario']; y cambia por: $dato = mysqli_query("SELECT acceso FROM mibasedatos WHERE id='$usuario');

Comment: Pese a que la idea inicial es buena, el resultado propuesto es un error de concepto. La consulta de permisos se tiene que hacer en el momento del login, NUNCA en cada página que se necesite. Aparte `mysqli_query`devuelve un objeto  `mysqli_result ` por lo que la comparación siguiente siempre va a ser `false`

Comment: @Patrick me sigue dando un error, esta vez en la línea 6 unexpected 'si' (T_STRING), esta es la línea 6: $si = "si";

Comment: @JDev Podría aplicarse en forma boleana con un campo INT de mi tabla? Dependiendo si el valor es TRUE o FALSE dejar o no ingresar a ciertas páginas

Comment: Si, de hecho es mas logico usar un int o un booleano que un String.

Comment: @JDev Podrías iluminarme con algún ejemplo? Sé que al Googlear los resultados son buenos, pero la mayoría son tutoriales con hasta 5 archivos dependientes entre sí para validar el acceso a un sitio

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esto, es mas o menos lo que se requiere. http://codigosdeprogramacion.com/2016/12/20/sistema-de-usuarios-y-sesiones-en-php-y-mysql-1-login-sesiones-y-logout/